# how to validate map as @RequestParam in spring controller

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, hashmap

how to validate map as `@RequestParam` in spring controller

```
public class Controller   {

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public ModelAndView requestMethod(@RequestParam Map<String, String> mapParam){

////some stuff here

};
```

Comment: You can use `Spring AOP` to validate the RequestParam.

Answer (score 0):

First of All you should send Map as RequestBody not as RequestParam.

You should create request DTO object instead of Map, to validate the Map you need to traverse and validate each key individually but using DTO you can directly validate using `@Valid` with your `@RequestBody`.

Refer this link for `@Valid` related code : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! But the application is already built and is stable one , they are passing key value pairs in url and accepting them through RequestParam. it cannot be changed to RequestBody or a DTO Object. My concern here is to somehow validate this param value !